# Golang flag parsing after an argument on command line

Tags: command-line, go

I am parsing command-line arguments. I use the following code:

```
var flagB = flag.Bool("b", false, "boolflag")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println(flag.NArg())
    fmt.Println("-b", *flagB)
}
```

When I execute the binary like this:

```
> test -b "random"
```

I get the expected output, becuase there is one argument, and the flag is set:

```
1
-b true
```

However, when I execute the binary the other way around:

```
> test "random" -b
```

I get this:

```
2
-b false
```

Now, the flag isn't recodnized any more as flag, but as another argument.

Why is it that way? Is there a definition that flags come first and then the arguments? I always thought that the "GNU-way" of passing and parsing arguments is: The first places after the binary are reserved for mandatory arguments. And after that you can put optional arguments and flags.

Comment: It's the way it is, because they chose to do it that way. Lots of things don't follow the gnu style (anything strictly POSIX for one). Go uses it's own simple parsing rules for `flag`, and if there's a demand for different flags, anyone could write a `gnuflag` or `getopt` package if they so choose (and it seems there's a few already if you search).

Comment: You are right, I completely missed this line while reading the docs: `Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument ("-" is a non-flag argument) or after the terminator "--".`

Comment: ha, I thought you were asking the philosophical "why did they do this?", not "where is this documented".

Comment: Short answer: Because it's always been this way until GNU came.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `flag` package does not use GNU parsing rules. The rules are explained [in the documentation for flag the package](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/). Your question is answered there:

> Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument ("-" is a non-flag argument) or after the terminator "--".

Comment: I'd be interested in the philosophical "why did they do this?", I'm often scratching my head at go's design and stdlib